# Android Fragment : which life cycle method to use for web service call

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an application in which several fragments are involved.
In each fragment I have to call web service to fetch data.

Currently I am calling web service from **onCreateView()** method of Fragment. Issue i am getting that whenever web service call is in progress and if device orientation is changed then new web service call starts invoking.

I think this might be because onCreateView() method gets called on configuration change.

How can I solve this. and which Life cycle method should I use to call web service so that it will be get called only once

Comment: I have the same issue. When I turn my tab 90 degrees, `onCreate` is called again and tries to reopen already opened socket, and since the socket was not closed prior to turning the tab, an error occurs and application aborts. Your case is different from mine though, because you receive no error, just a new connection is started

Comment: I tried to find some specific event in order to intercept orientation change and close the socket before activity restart, but no success. One thing for sure, `onCreate()` is called when orientation changes

Comment: PS. Hmm, just realized that I could check whether socket is opened or not at the very beginning of `onCreate()` and close it, if it is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this by following workaround

1. Create an operation identifier for each web service call method. E.g. for example "Authentication" for login call
2. Create one object of ArrayList say currentTasks

   ```
   ArrayList<String> currentTasks = new ArrayList<String>();
   ```
3. In every method where I am calling web service, check if operation identifier of corresponding method is already present in ArrayList. If not then start operation.

   ```
   String operationId = "Authentication";
   if(currentTasks.indexOf(operationId) == -1)
   {
     <do web service call operation here>
      currentTasks.add(operationId);
   }
   ```
4. Method in which above operation's response is receiving, remove operation identifier from ArrayList

   ```
    if(currentTasks.indexOf("Authentication") != -1){
       currentTasks.remove("Authentication");
    }
   ```

This will ensure that call will not go to web method which is currently in progress.

I know this is not the best way to achieve it and this might not the best practice to follow but for now this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your web service code is getting restarted due to a device orientation change, than you're probably using an `AsyncTask`. This is a common problem with AsyncTasks and you have several ways to solve it.

One common workaround is to wrap your AsyncTask around an invisible `Fragment` and make sure this fragment does not get destroyed and recreated again during an orientation change. Check out this tutorial on how to do it: [Retaining Objects Across Config Changes](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)

Comment: can you provide some code which can explain this more?

Comment: Check out the link I added above. If you go to that site, look in the "Recommended: Manage the Object Inside a Retained Fragment" section for a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use a static variable pointing to asynctask. Create and call an AsyncTask if variable is not null.

Regards, 
Prateek

Comment: Be careful with this approach. Holding a static variable during rotation changes is very prone to memory leaks.

Comment: @Henrique Can you please explain the case for that

Comment: The complete explanation is a topic on its own and too long to be added as a comment, but just as an example, let's say you have a static AsyncTask which holds a reference to it's owner Activity. If the Activity gets destroyed because the user left it, but the AsyncTask hasn't completed yet, the Activity will still be kept alive since there's a live reference to it. So we're basically keeping stuff around that shouldn't be there and should've been cleared by the garbage collector. Try searching for android memory leaks for other special cases similar to this one.